# DenyUsers userid@host issue in sshd_config

Tags: users, configuration, sshd

In order to restrict shared users moving around environments, I implemented DenyUsers userID@host. But this is working only on few hosts. There are some hosts where I implemented the same in sshd_config but not working. Can someone help from where I can troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: “Not working” means... users can log in to places where you don’t want them to?

Comment: userID is able to ssh from restricted host1 whereas userID should not be able to ssh from the host per sshd_config rule DenyUsers userID@host1

Comment: If this you want to deny only *SSH* access you could do it trough **iptables**

Comment: Will try IPtables on failed servers. Will see if that works

Comment: Show configuration and logfiles of authentication attempts. Specify what changes from hosts where it works to hosts where it does not. Basic information needed when asking for solutions.

Comment: @k.Cyborg at iptables level you will not get access to information related to user ids

Comment: @PatrickMevzek you're right! I think that with some time to spend you could write some scripts to fix this "problem" and make a log related to iptables denay/allow access, it will be an interesting project!

Comment: @k.Cyborg I see no point in doing that, AllowUsers and DenyUsers are here for that. iptables is typically a level 3 or 4 (IP, TCP, UDP, etc.) tool for filtering, stuff at level 7 should be filtered by each application, based on its needs. Otherwise have a look at `fail2ban` if you do not know this tool yet.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek let me get some info about `fail2ban`, also let me do some research about Allow/Deny Users. A question: **iptables** doesn't work in lvl4 of the TCP/IP model? I think you can filter apps using iptables...Am I wrong? Otherwise: thanks for the directions!!! :-)

Comment: I wrote "typically"! You can do all sort of things with iptables and even poke inside of packets and match on arbitrary strings. But this is not the typical use, which is filtering on IP, TCP or UDP levels. We are also drifting from the subject of this question.

Comment: Does DenyUser have some thing to do with RHEL version as well? The only common thing I found in list of hosts that were not running was , they all were 7 boxes

Comment: @user227863 try using `userid@ip.address` in the DenyHosts rule rather than `userid@hostname`.  If there's a DNS problem causing the IP address to fail to be resolved (e.g. your .in-addr.arpa zone isn't correct) then the ssh client's hostname will not be known to the ssh server....so user@hostname will fail to be blocked.

Comment: @k.Cyborg iptables is the wrong tool for this.   iptables can block entire hosts (actually IP addresses) from connecting to particular ports (e.g. sshd on port 22).  It can **NOT** block specific users from those IP addresses while allowing others - with `iptables`, blocking is all or nothing.  The `DenyUsers` configuration directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` does that.

Answer (score 1):

ok. I finally checked secure logs and it turns out to be DNS name resolving issue. I quickly used the protocol DenyUsers userID@IPAddress as per @cas solution and it worked.

Comment: you should accept your own answer to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: Apologies. Not aware of this. Will ensure I donot add my comments as answer @cas.

Comment: That's not what I was saying.  It's a good answer, it solved your problem, you should accept it.  It's perfectly OK on SE sites to accept your own answer.

Comment: oh sorry misread it :) @cas

Comment: No problem. It didn't occur to me that my comment might have been misread as sarcastic.  Really, there was and is no sarcasm intended. And it's good to have Questions resolved with an accepted Answer.